# Surface mount power outlet under kitchen sink

Tags: electrical

Can I surface mount a power outlet under the kitchen sink?  Or does it have to be a box that sits on the surface of the cabinet wall?

Answer (score 2):

In the US under the NEC:

A receptacle or other box **in** a sink base or other cabinet can be either surface mount or flush. There is no requirement or restriction for either.

Comment: Again, maybe the downvoter can explain what was incorrect about this answer. I don't care about the two points, but I am curious as to why someone thinks this is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

A box can be mounted below the counter top (on the face of the cabinet) not more than 12" below the counter top 210.52.5 exception 5.

Comment: Can that box be mounted on the floor of the cabinet directly below the garbage disposal?

Comment: I think part of the question is *surface mount*. Code generally requires that for surface mounting, only armored cable, conduit or metal raceways and surface mont type boxes be used in most areas, especially where NM cables could be damaged.

Comment: That is if the cables are accessible from the same side of the surface as the surface mounted box.  If the surface mount box is supplied from behind the surface, then regular NM is fine.  It you can look under your sink and see NM (non-armored) cable, then you're at risk of failing inspection.

Comment: What you quoted is for a required counter-serving receptacle and is not relevant to the question. He's asking about putting on inside the cabinet under the sink.